# Why didn't God create a simple system/universe?

Tags: brahma, creation, universe

Why create such complicated texts why create such a hard law to understand law of karma? Why didn't create everything simple where action,reaction ,law of karma , divine powers were visible to everyone? Like somebody reciting the law of god above the clouds regularly to everyone, then I think there wouldn't be any atheist?

Comment: God is not at fault. We are at fault. It’s our problem if we cloud our minds with made up situations.